# I got an incorrect solution when trying to find keys in a functional dependency

Tags: functional-dependencies

Hi i have textbook question to find the keys in the relation
ACD->B, AB->E, A->C, AD->E, AE->D
and I worked out The keys are AE, AD, AB and ACD, but the text book answer says that the keys are just AE, AD and AB and not ACD

it does not offer any reason as to why ACD is not considered a key
i worked it out like this 
(ACD)+ = ACD -> ABCD -> ABCDE

can anyone offer me an explanation as to why ACD is not considered a key?

Answer (score 1):

A candidate key is a minimal superkey.

ACD is not a candidate key, because it's not a *minimal* superkey.

ACD is a superkey, because ACD+ = ABCDE. It's not a minimal superkey, because a subset of it has the same closure. AD+ = ABCDE.

Answer (score 0):

You have `A -> C` so A determines C. Hence C can't be in a key that A is also in.

Comment: how would i write formally disprove that ACD is not a key? would i just write something like ACD is not a key because C is a secondary attribute?